# Is there a way to process a credit card transaction asychronously and be PCI compliant?

Tags: pci-dss

If I had to store credit card details temporarily to shove it to the processor using an asychronous worker, I know that that information must be encrypted.

To get it to the worker, however, it must be **stored** at least in RAM. How is it possible to do this but remain PCI compliant? [This](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf) states:

> 3.2.2 Do not store the card verification code or value (three-digit or four-digit number printed on the front or back of a payment card) used to verify card-not-present transactions.

Or is it impossible to be PCI compliant and use asynchronous workers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAM is volatile and is not considered storage for PCI-DSS purposes - so long as the device that contains the RAM is otherwise PCI-DSS compliant.

In a similar fashion, temporary storage of the CVC/CVV on disc is not considered "storage" if the storage is highly volatile. For example, the operating system's swap space.

Comment: Can you point me to any sources, so I can show my colleagues? It looks like I was confused with the meaning of "storage", then.

Comment: "Storage" in PCI-DSS would have to mean persistent memory, otherwise all servers would need [Homomorphically Encrypted RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) which would be profoundly more expensive than ECC RAM which is [already quite expensive](http://superuser.com/q/367368). Might as well has mandatory two-factor-auth credit cards in that case.

Comment: @RamonTayag An example in *1.3.7* of [this doc](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/navigating_dss_v20.pdf). PCI-DSS does acknowledge [memory scraping risks](http://pciguru.wordpress.com/tag/ram-scraping/) so you will need to secure the server in all the other ways. Also consider if direct PCI-DSS compliance [is worth it](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/42352/30521).